# monthly report for Project and total billingtime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create sql statement to show how many total time spent on project in  monthly basses can someone help me
sql query

```
SELECT Projects.projectID,
        Projects.projectName,
        billingsTimes.actualTotalTime,
        billingsTimes.taskID,
        Tasks.taskName
  FROM Projects_tasks
       INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects_tasks.projectID = Projects.projectID
       INNER JOIN Tasks ON Projects_tasks.taskID = Tasks.taskID
       INNER JOIN billingsTimes ON Tasks.taskID = billingsTimes.taskID
```

[image]

DB diagram

Comment: This is not [tag:data-mining], but plain old SQL. removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.projectID,
    p.projectName,
    year(bt.createdOn) as Year,
    month(bt.createdOn) as Month,
    sum(bt.actualTotalTime) as TotalTime
from Projects_tasks pt
inner join Projects p on pt.projectID = p.projectID
inner join Tasks t on p.taskID = t.taskID
inner join billingsTimes bt on t.taskID = bt.taskID
group by p.projectID,
    p.projectName,
    year(bt.createdOn),
    month(bt.createdOn),
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?:

```
SELECT  Projects.projectID,
        Projects.projectName,
        SUM(billingsTimes.actualTotalTime),
        billingsTimes.taskID,
        Tasks.taskName, 
        MONTH(billingTimes.createdOn),
        YEAR(billingTimes.createdOn)
FROM    Projects_tasks
        INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects_tasks.projectID = Projects.projectID
        INNER JOIN Tasks ON Projects_tasks.taskID = Tasks.taskID
        INNER JOIN billingsTimes ON Tasks.taskID = billingsTimes.taskID
GROUP BY
        Projects.projectID,
        Projects.projectName,
        billingsTimes.taskID,
        Tasks.taskName, 
        MONTH(billingTimes.createdOn),
        YEAR(billingTimes.createdOn)
```